# Trouble downloading image from URL from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm having trouble getting my image to download in from user input. Whenever I try to upload the image I get the error screen. I'm working in Xcode 9 with swift 4.0.

```
if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2){
    let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    let storageItem = Storage.storage().reference().child(imgUid)
    storageItem.putData(imgData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Couldn't Upload Image")
        } else {
            print("Uploaded")
            storageItem.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if url != nil {
                    self.setUser(img: url!.absoluteString)
                }
            }
        )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting?

Comment: its just the print( "Couldn't upload image") error I have written in my code. I have no problem building and running my app. I just can't get images to upload.

Comment: can you add something like ```print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")``` underneath your current print for error, that should hopefully give you some context of what exactly the error you are getting is.

Comment: this is what the console reads:error: Optional("An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.")

Comment: Try to exclude your meta data and just provide nil.

Comment: Sorry was busy at work, can you see if you can get the response from the server side? Hopefully that will give you a rejection reason.

Comment: This is what the console reads before printing "couldn't upload image".  [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}